# Aps.Net MVC same table but unique ID's per user

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a very basic app that allows customers to create quotes & I need each user to have their own individual quote ID's (basically it a very simple multi tenant app).

For example when "USER 1" creates quotes, his quote ID's should be 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8..etc..

When "USER 2" creates quotes, the ID's should be reset/unique to him so his first quote ID's would also be 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8..etc..

Basically, each user is a competing business that so they need separate quote ID's. Apart from the unique quote ID's, the quotes table & all other tables will be exactly the same for every user.

What would be the best approach for this? Create a separate "quotes" table per user? And how would I do this? I am using mvc 5, ef 6 code first with migrations & want to keep it as simple as I can.

Here is an example of my quotes model.

```
    public class Quote
{
    [Key]
    public int QuoteID { get; set; }
    public DateTime QuoteDate { get; set; }
    public string ClientsName { get; set; }

    //[ForeignKey("ApplicationUsers")]
    [Column("OwnerID")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
}
```

**SIMPLE SOLUTION:**

As per Richards suggestion below, I am just converting the QuoteID's into hashes using http://hashids.org/net/

```
// original QuoteID = 120
var userID = User.Identity.GetUserId();
var hashids = new Hashids(userID, 4, "123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ");
var hashedID = hashids.Encode(item.QuoteID);
var unhashedID = hashids.Decode(hashedID);
// hashedID = 6DBD
// unhashedID = 120
```

The will make sure no one can tell how many quotes their competitors have which is all that I needed - thanks Richard for getting me back on track again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd be reluctant to add a quotes table per user, as you might run into problems needing to update the app/run migrations every time you add a customer.

Firstly, do you really need the auto numbered IDs exposed as the unique key? Might you be better off looking at some kind of short random string that could be in the URL - e.g. quotes.com/quote/m2dhfy ? You could generate that in your app and use it as the lookup key (I'd maintain an autonumber identity column as well).

Secondly, if you do really need those sequential IDs, you would need to have a composite key of UserId and QuoteID. That way in your URL you could have quotes.com/client1/1 and do the db lookup on UserID AND QuoteID

Comment: They have to be separate ID's so each business does not know how many quotes their competitors are doing.. But, a short random string is actually a great idea! I don't know why I did not think of that. I guess sometimes the simplest solutions get missed..lol

Comment: I have update my question with Richards solution so hopefully it can help someone else.

Comment: glad to help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your model is correct. You don`t need to create any other ids, symply select quotes from database, order them by date.
In the page symply generate number like this:

```
@{var i = 0;}
@foreach (var item in userQuotes){
    i++
    <tr>
        <td>@i</td> // this will symply itterate rows for user.
        <td>@item.ClientsName</td>
        ....
        <td>@item.AnyData</td>
    </tr>
}
```

Hope this will help you.